# Update a property in mongodb collection using ejs and node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, ejs

A beginner with node.js servers, mongodb and ejs, I am trying to create a member schema. I'm having difficulty updating or adding values to fields of a collection already created. In the "/" route the values for name and email fields are added to a new member, after being redirected to "/page1" route i want the user to add another value which i will appended to that particular member. I ann==

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const ejs = require("ejs");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");


const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
app.use(express.static("public"));

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/membersDB", {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true
});

const memberSchema = {
  name: String,
  email: String,
  theme: String,
  guests: String
};

const Member = mongoose.model("Member", memberSchema);


app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  Member.deleteMany({}, function(err, members){
    if (err) {
      console.log("Unsuccessfully removed collection.");
    } else {
      console.log("Collection successfully removed.");
      res.render("home");
    }
  });

});

app.post("/home", function(req, res) {
  const member = new Member({
    name: req.body.memberName,
    email: req.body.memberEmail
  });
  member.save(function(err) {
    if (!err) {
      console.log("Member saved successfully.", member.name);
      res.redirect("page1");
    } else {
      console.log("Request unsuccessful.");
    }
  });
});

app.get("/page1", function(req, res) {
  Member.find({}, function (err, members){
    res.render("page1", {
      members: members
    });
  })

});

app.post("/page1", function(req, res) {
  Member.updateOne({},{$set: {"theme": req.body.style}
});
});
```

Below is the page1.ejs code

```
<%- include ("partials/header"); -%>

<div class="section">

  <% members.forEach(function(member) { %>

  <h1>Welcome, <%= member.name %></h1>

  <% }); %>


  <h1>For Family or Friends?</h1>
  <form class="" action="/page1" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">

      <button class="form-control" type="submit" value="style">Family</button>
      <button class="form-control" type="submit" value="style">Friends</button>
    </div>

  </form>
</div>

<%- include ("partials/footer"); -%>
```

For test purposes the collection is emptied before so there is only one member to deal with

Comment: Everything is successful up until the app.post("/page1" ... I would like the value of the button submitted to be added to a field of membersDB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
under this const Member = mongoose.model("Member", memberSchema);

var object = new Member({name:"Arjun",email:"something@some.com",theme:"asdgjh",guests:"guest"});

Then a new row will be added to the member collection

=================================================================
In the EJS file
<div class="container p-4 border border-primary">
        <form action="/created" class="form-group" method="post">
            <label for="title">Title</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="name" type="text" placeholder="name" id="title">
            <label for="title">email</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="email" type="email" placeholder="email" id="title">
 <label for="title">Theme</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="theme" type="email" placeholder="email" id="title">
 <label for="title">guest</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="guest" type="text" placeholder="email" id="title">
            
            <button class="btn btn-success"  type="submit">Create post</button>
        </form>
    </div>

================================================================================

Then in the javascript file

app.post("/created",(req,res)=>{
var name = req.body.name;
var email = req.body.email;
var theme = req.body.theme;
var guest = req.body.theme;
obj.create({name:name, email:email, theme:theme, guest:guest});
res.render("your_ejs_page");
})
```